debezium postgres source connector kafka filter based on date
I have a debezium postgres source connector capturing change data in a table and would like to filter the rows going to Kafka based on a date field in the table.
I have been able to filter on other fields with integer data types and char types, but the postgres date in the kafka message is in the postgres format of number of days since epoch.  For example in the pgAdmin my createDate column shows as 2009-01-01 but the kafka message has 13879 (number of day since 1970).  I tried using transforms.filter.condition:"value.after.createDate > 12418 (Jan 1, 2004) but that did not work.  I also tried to compare to a date string but that also did not work.  Here is my connector config that works filtering on an integer field.
{
   "name": "postgres-connector",
   "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
      "tasks.max": "100",
      "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal",
      "database.port": "5432",
      "database.user": "testUser",
      "database.dbname" : "postgres",
      "topic.prefix": "postgresTest2",
      "schema.include.list": "public",
      "time.precision.mode": "connect",
      "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
      "transforms": "filter",
      "transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter",
      "transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy",
      "transforms.filter.condition": "value.after.testInt > 5"
      }
}

And here is a sample of the kafka message I get from the connector.
{
    "before": null,
    "after": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "'name-8'",
        "createDate": 14245,
        "lastDate": 16436,
        "timestamp": "08:20:30Z",
        "testInt": 8
    },
    "source": {
        "version": "2.7.1.Final",
        "connector": "postgresql",
        "name": "postgresTest2",
        "ts_ms": 1730840079375,
        "snapshot": "last",
        "db": "postgres",
        "sequence": "[null,\"24444976\"]",
        "ts_us": 1730840079375132,
        "ts_ns": 1730840079375132000,
        "schema": "public",
        "table": "test-table-1",
        "txId": 736,
        "lsn": 24444976,
        "xmin": null
    },
    "transaction": null,
    "op": "r",
    "ts_ms": 1730840079747,
    "ts_us": 1730840079747671,
    "ts_ns": 1730840079747671600
}

Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.
